# Thread, Network and Python

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

I'm trying to create a little chat program that connect two (or more) computers, so I tried this :

```
    import socket

    tcpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    tcpSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

    tcpSocket.bind(("0.0.0.0",8000))

    tcpSocket.listen(3)

    print "Waiting for a Client ... "
    (client, (ip,sock)) = tcpSocket.accept()

    print "Received connection from : ",ip

    print "Starting ECHO output ..."

    data = 'dump'

    client.send("Enter you're name : ")
    name=client.recv(1024)
    name=name.strip()

    while len(data) :
        send_data = raw_input("Me : ")
        try :
            client.send("Server : "+send_data)
            client.send("\n"+name+" : ")
        except :
            print "Connection lost !"
            break
        data = client.recv(2048)
        data = data.strip()
        print name+" : "+data

    print "Closing connection ..."
    client.close()

    print "Shutting down server ..."
    tcpSocket.close()
```

And it worked well, the only problem is that I can't connect more than one computer to the server! I tried with the thread module by using this fonction:

```
import socket
import thread

def thread_send() :



print "Received connection from : ",ip

    print "Starting ECHO output ..."

    data = 'dump'

    client.send("Enter you're name : ")
    name=client.recv(1024)
    name=name.strip()

    while len(data) :
        send_data = raw_input("Me : ")
        try :
            client.send("Server : "+send_data)
            client.send("\n"+name+" : ")
        except :
            print "Connection lost !"
            break
        data = client.recv(2048)
        data = data.strip()
        print name+" : "+data


tcpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

tcpSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

tcpSocket.bind(("0.0.0.0",8000))

tcpSocket.listen(5)

print "Waiting for a Client ... "

(client, (ip,sock)) = tcpSocket.accept()

for i in range(5) :

    thread.start_new_thread(thread_send,())

while True :
    pass

print "Closing connection ..."
client.close()

print "Shutting down server ..."
tcpSocket.close()
```

But it doesn't work :/

Comment: Where is your driver program that calls this function ? Basically, you call "accept" on main thread and pass the new connection / socket to a new thread.

Comment: Ok thanks, so i tried to call "accept" outside the function but now the client connects to the five threads, but what i want is 5 clients connecting to one server :/ (I edited my post to show the entire code !)

Comment: No, it doesnt work like that. 1) Run the accept in while loop (for multiple clients). #2) Each time accept returns, start a new thread and pass it the new socket (client) and other required details (ip and sock). #3) How to finish a thread servicing a connection depends on your way.

Comment: In your case, every time you are getting a connection, you are starting 5 threads which is incorrect. You need to start 1 thread per connection (NOTE: not suitable if you are planning to use this in any kind of scalable app)

Comment: Well that's the problem, how do I do that? I am new in threads and stuff! So excuse me for my lack of knowledge :p

Comment: The networking code in this question (and in the accepted answer) is wrong.  TCP is stream-oriented but you're treating it as if it's message-oriented.  `send` is not guaranteed to send the *entire* string you pass it.  `recv` guarantees nothing about how many bytes it will return.  To get started with network programming, I suggest you take a look at http://twistedmatrix.com/ instead of the socket and threading modules.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Please read the question on what was required to understand

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Also its wrong to say "send" is not guaranteed to send the "entire" string. TCP does provide this basic guarantee (unless if you get ETIMEDOUT or broken pipe).Its just that the message "might" be broken into 1 or more packets

Comment: @level-beginner: What jean has mentioned is correct, you need to implement some protocol so that you know the message boundaries. Twisted would be an overkill, you can try to implement it on your own or use asynchat module

Comment: @ArunMu: Sorry, you are wrong.  Please read http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is an example of how you do it. Sorry, I have not tested this code nor ran it to check for any kind of syntax issue, this is just for giving an idea.

```
def thread_send(cli_sock):
    data = 'dump'

    cli_sock.send("Enter you're name : ")
    name=cli_sock.recv(1024)

    if len(name) == 0:   ## If client disconnected or terminated
        return

    name=name.strip()

    while len(data) :
        send_data = raw_input("Me : ")
        try :
            cli_sock.send("Server : "+send_data)
            cli_sock.send("\n"+name+" : ")
        except :
            print "Connection lost !"
            break
        data = client.recv(2048)
        data = data.strip()
        print name+" : "+data



serv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv_sock.bind(('localhost', 8080))
serv_sock.listen(1)
print "After listen...waiting for accept\n"
try:
    while True:
        client_sock, address = serv_sock.accept()
        print "Connection accepted\n"
        thread.start_new_thread(thread_send, (client_sock))
finally:
    serv_sock.close()
```